# BSTS Package: Error in the Mean Absolute Percentage Estimate (MAPE) as Inf % in a Bayesian Inference with MCMC Plot using ggplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, bayesian, mcmc

**Overview:**

I am conducting a **Bayesian time series analysis with mcmc simulations**. To visualise the **mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)** for the analysis, I am producing a plot **using ggplot()**.

**I am following this tutorial below:**

https://michaeldewittjr.com/dewitt_blog/posts/2018-07-05-bayesian-time-series-analysis-with-bsts_files/

**Problems:**

In the past, I have successfully produced this plot (see plot 1 below) with my R-code that can be found in this previously asked [Stack Overflow question.](http://https:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708201/production-of-a-bsts-mean-absolute-percentage-error-mape-plot-from-a-bayesian). The mean holdout value was **32.52 %**, and the actual and fitted data plotted nicely (plot 1).

However, I have not used this code for a couple of months, and today, I needed to extract the plot for work. To my dismay, the R-code that was previously working absolutely fine is no longer working (see plot 2). I have tried to adapt the R-code below in the data frame **d2 (see R-code below)** as well as checking the R-code in the plotting object itself (produced using **ggplot())**, and I just cannot find the answer.

**For example:**

1. The **y-axis** is ranging from **0 to 15,000.00** in **plot 2**, whereas, the correct data range should be between **0-120** as shown in **plot 1** (when the code was working).
2. The **MAPE value in plot 2** is **Inf %**, when the correct **MAPE value is 32.52 %** (see plot 1 - produced with the R-code in the link above to my previous Stack Overflow question).

However, the only difference between my R-code in this question and my previous question was that I needed to add .001 to the **x object (see R-code below)** since the **bsts() function** would not accept zero values for the months of June and July (see the data frame below - BSTS_df).

When I run the **MAPE object**, I have noticed that the outcome is **infinity (see below)**, which is very strange:

```
                      MAPE
                      1  Inf
```

I have also noticed that the values in the column **UL** produced from the **posterior.interval object** is ranging up to approximately 17,500.00, which I assume is not correct (see below):-

```
           LL          UL       Date
1  3.05009089  9214.58787 2017-01-01
2  2.74650830  7143.70646 2017-02-01
3  5.68858210  6537.04558 2017-03-01
4  2.76432668  2836.65981 2017-04-01
5  0.78042088  2249.52498 2017-05-01
6  0.04854900    88.57707 2017-06-01
7  0.03650557   145.12395 2017-07-01
8  2.70009631  5338.68317 2017-08-01
9  3.08234007  2329.57492 2017-09-01
10 2.26410227 17146.68785 2017-10-01
11 1.22190125 15561.66013 2017-11-01
12 2.14859047  3326.09852 2017-12-01
```

If anyone can help me fix these errors, I would be deeply appreciative since my R-code was working extremely well beforehand.

Many thanks in advance.

**Plot 1**

[image]

**Plot 2**

[image]

**R-Code**

```
##Open packages for the time series analysis

library(lubridate)
library(bsts)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

###################################################################################
##Time Series Bayesian Inference Model with mcmc using the bsts() function
##################################################################################

##Change the Year column into YY/MM/DD format for the first of evey month per year
BSTS_df$Year <- lubridate::ymd(paste0(BSTS_df$Year, BSTS_df$Month,"-01"))

##Order the Year column in YY/MM/DD format into the correct sequence: Jan-Dec
allDates <- seq.Date(
                    min(BSTS_df$Year),
                    max(BSTS_df$Year),
                   "month")

##Produce and arrange the new data frame ordered by the first of evey month in YY/MM/DD format
BSTS_new_df <- BSTS_df %>%
                      right_join(data.frame(Year = allDates), by = c("Year")) %>%
                      dplyr::arrange(Year) %>%
                      tidyr::fill(Frequency, .direction = "down")

##Create a time series object
myts2 <- ts(BSTS_new_df$Frequency, start=c(2015, 1), end=c(2017, 12), frequency=12)

##Upload the data into the windows() function
x <- window(myts2, start=c(2015, 01), end=c(2016, 12))
y <- log(x+.001)

##Produce a list for the object ss
ss <- list()
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y, nseasons = 12)
ss <- AddLocalLevel(ss, y)

##Produce the bsts model using the bsts() function
bsts.model <- bsts(y, state.specification = ss,  niter = 100, ping = 0, seed = 123)

##Open plotting window
dev.new()

##Plot the bsts.model
plot(bsts.model)

##Get a suggested number of burns
burn<-bsts::SuggestBurn(0.1, bsts.model)

##Predict

p<-predict.bsts(bsts.model, horizon = 12, burn=burn, quantiles=c(.25, .975))

p$mean

##Actual vs predicted

d2 <- data.frame(
      # fitted values and predictions
      c(exp(as.numeric(-colMeans(bsts.model$one.step.prediction.errors[-(1:burn),])+y)),  
      exp(as.numeric(p$mean))),
      # actual data and dates
      as.numeric(BSTS_new_df$Frequency),
      as.Date(BSTS_new_df$Year))

###Rename the columns
names(d2) <- c("Fitted", "Actual", "Date")

### MAPE (mean absolute percentage error)
MAPE <- dplyr::filter(d2, lubridate::year(Date)>=2017) %>%
                                dplyr::summarise(MAPE=mean(abs(Actual-Fitted)/Actual))


### 95% forecast credible interval
posterior.interval <- cbind.data.frame(
                                  exp(as.numeric(p$interval[1,])),
                                  exp(as.numeric(p$interval[2,])),
                                  tail(d2,12)$Date)

##Rename the columns
names(posterior.interval) <- c("LL", "UL", "Date")

### Join intervals to the forecast
d3 <- left_join(d2, posterior.interval, by="Date")

##Open plotting window
dev.new()

### Plot actual versus predicted with credible intervals for the holdout period
ggplot(data=d3, aes(x=Date)) +
       geom_line(aes(y=Actual, colour = "Actual"), size=1.2) +
       geom_line(aes(y=Fitted, colour = "Fitted"), size=1.2, linetype=2) +
       theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
       geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2017-12-01")), linetype=2) +
       geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=LL, ymax=UL), fill="grey", alpha=0.5) +
       ggtitle(paste0("BSTS -- Holdout MAPE = ", round(100*MAPE,2), "%")) +
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

**Data Frame - BSTS_df**

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Month = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", "December", 
"February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", 
"October", "September"), class = "factor"), Frequency = c(36, 
28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 
7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 
43, 38), Days_Sea_Month = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 
29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 
28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: From a quick look, the problem might be related to the fact that BSTS is running a montecarlo simulation which, by design, has a random component. Probably the 1st time you ran it you got a reasonable result and this 2nd time your results have gone wild. You can easily check if that's the case by running your code several times, and checking the output. As far as I remember, although I'm not fully sure, BSTS does not have a way to set a seed. But anyway, this is a symptom that you have an inestable model. The results in the 1st plot don't look so great anyway.... hope this helps in any way